# "Named tuples" in r

Tags: r

If you load the pracma package into the r console and type

```
gammainc(2,2)
```

you get

```
   lowinc    uppinc    reginc 
0.5939942 0.4060058 0.5939942
```

This looks like some kind of a named tuple or something.

But, I can't work out how to extract the number below the `lowinc`, namely `0.5939942`. The code `(gammainc(2,2))[1]` doesn't work, we just get

```
   lowinc
0.5939942
```

which isn't a number.

How is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double brackets will strip the dimension names

```
gammainc(2,2)[[1]]
gammainc(2,2)[["lowinc"]]
```

I don't claim it to be intuitive, or obvious, but it is mentioned in the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing):

> For vectors and matrices the [[ forms are rarely used, although they
>   have some slight semantic differences from the [ form (e.g. it drops
>   any names or dimnames attribute, and that partial matching is used for
>   character indices).

The partial matching can be employed like this

```
gammainc(2, 2)[["low", exact=FALSE]]
```

Answer (score 8):

As can be checked with `str(gammainc(2,2)[1])` and `class(gammainc(2,2)[1])`, the output mentioned in the OP is in fact a number. It is just a *named* number. The names used as attributes of the vector are supposed to make the output easier to understand.

The function `unname()` can be used to obtain the numerical vector without names:

```
unname(gammainc(2,2))
#[1] 0.5939942 0.4060058 0.5939942
```

To select the first entry, one can use:

```
unname(gammainc(2,2))[1]
#[1] 0.5939942
```

In this specific case, a clearer version of the same might be:

```
unname(gammainc(2,2)["lowinc"])
```

Answer (score 3):

In R vectors may have names() attribute. This is an example:

```
vector <- c(1, 2, 3)
names(vector) <- c("first", "second", "third")
```

If you display vector, you should probably get desired output:

```
vector

> vector
 first second  third 
     1      2      3
```

To ensure what type of output you get after the function you can use:

```
class(your_function())
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but I still don't understand how to extract the desired value. Can you be a little more explicit?

Comment: This means, that your extraction was probably correct and you extracted a "numeric" type.

Comment: Okay. I tried is.numeric on the output and it certainly returns "TRUE". Just seems kind of weird; I mean, there's junk information floating around that I can't get rid of.

Comment: If you want to delete names use `names(vector) <- NULL`