# Call amelia imputations in a function to calculate y-hat after multiple imputation

Tags: r, imputation

What I ultimately want to do is get y-hat scores after a multiple imputation, but Amelia does not provide fitted values. I have code that does it with a specific data set, but I'm trying to make a function that will do this regardless of the data set. Something like:

```
yhat<-function(a.out,num.obs,num.imp,model.qe){}
```

Where `num.imp` is the number of imputations used in `amelia`, or `m`. This is where I am stuck, though:

If `a.out` is an `amelia` object and `names(a.out$imputations)[1]` returns `"imp1"`, why does `a.out$imputations$names(a.out$imputations)[1]` not return the same thing as `a.out$imputations$"imp1"`?

For `a.out$imputations$names(a.out$imputations)[1]`, R says: `Error: attempt to apply non-function`.

How can I create a generic call for the individual imputations and the variables within?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question. What have you tried so far for your function? Also, clarifying the question itself would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry. So, I have an amelia object, `a.out`. I want to call on individual values. For example, I can get the first observation of the first variable from the first imputation with `a.out$imputations$imp1[1,1]`. However, I want the last part to defined by a function, something like `a.out$imputations[i,j,k]`, where i is the imputation, j is the variable, and k is the observation. For example, if i=1, j=1, k=1, then `a.out$imputations[i,j,k]` would be equivalent to `a.out$imputations$imp1[1,1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example taken from the Amelia docs

```
library(Amelia)

data(africa)
a.out <- amelia(x = africa, cs = "country", ts = "year", logs = "gdp_pc")
```

`a.out$imputations` is a list

```
str(a.out$imputations)
```

Elements in a list can be called either by name or numeric index

```
head(a.out$imputations$imp1)
head(a.out$imputations[["imp1"]])
head(a.out$imputations[[1]])
```

Each imputation is a data frame. A data frame is just a particular kind of list and elements can be called in that manner.

```
head(a.out$imputations[[1]]$country)
head(a.out$imputations[[1]][["country"]])
head(a.out$imputations[[1]][[2]])
head(a.out$imputations[[1]][2])
```

The last of those methods differ from the rest in that it returns a one-column data frame, while the others return a vector.

To extract an individual value entirely by numeric indices you could do f.ex

```
a.out$imputations[[1]][3, 2]
```

or

```
a.out$imputations[[1]][[2]][3]
```

Comment: Thanks! The `[[]]` double bracket is new to me. I suppose I missed it when I jumped in head first.

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt: You can find some info in the docs by calling `?"[["` or `?Extract`, but it can seem a little dense. Info is spread around on this site as well, but it's hard to find if you don't know what you're looking for, and even if you are, it pops up in odd places. For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507521/named-tuples-in-r/37507740#37507740) where the question title gives little indication that it contains information on double square brackets.